# Broken texture in voxel character after importing to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, textures, voxel

When I export the visual character I have all the textures then after rigging and animating when I add it to unity and apply texture half of the texture is missing

I tried re importing, re rigging, extracting texture and applying it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to upload the character and extract the textures and materials from the character and  add the color pallet to the material tab **albedo map**
.
[Extracting the materials and textures from an asset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E69z.jpg)
.
[Colors of the asset that you have to add to he material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Ovh.jpg)
.
[the place where you have to add the color pallet in the previous pic to get the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXj1y.jpg)